# Trouble with Pagination in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to add pagination on my news app but when I scroll down I can find only the objects.

Ts file:

```
doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
    console.log('Begin async operation');
    setTimeout(() => {
    this.api.getPosts().subscribe(data=>{
    console.log(data)
    this.getData = data
  })
   console.log('Async operation has ended');
    infiniteScroll.complete();
   }, 500);
 }
```

Html part:

```
     <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let i of getData">{{i}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
      <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

I want content should continue loading as I scroll down the page

Answer (score 0):

```
  doInfinite(infiniteScroll: any) { 
  //Do here your API call with pagination param
  infiniteScroll.complete()
  }
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please [edit] your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22048982)

Comment: here I can't retrieve the data. it displays old same log again and again in console

Comment: because of u assign data direct to this.getdata. insted of that use loop for that and push new data with old data